# Permanently assign a value to a keyboard shortcut for pasting

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

There are some values I have to use repeatedly but are too complicated to remember so I have to keep looking them up.

Is there a way to permanently assign a value to a keyboard shortcut for pasting?

Comment: What do you want to paste exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to write a tiny script which resides in your notification area.
Everytime when you press your shortcut the script will automatically insert your desired values.

[image]

#### How to

1. Download & install the programm
2. Open a new text file and copy & paste the following

   ```
   x::Send, MyFirstValue
   y::Send, MySecondValue
   z::Send, MyThirdValue
   ```
3. Modify `x`, `y`, `z` to your own desired shortcuts and your own values
4. Save the file as `MyScript.ahk`
5. Go to `..\AutoHotKey\Compiler\Ahk2Exe.exe` and use it  to convert your AHK file to an executable

Place a shortcut to that EXE in your startup folder to enable your new shortcut by default.

Comment: This rocks!  You made my day!

Answer (score 0):

to avoid using a 3rd party tool if your keyboard has favorite keys

1. Create .bat file (like myValue1.bat) with content: 
   `echo MyFirstValue| clip`
2. Assign this bath file to a favorite key of your keyboard
   Note: the echo includes a return